# Why this is saying me 'Could not find matching close tag for "<%" '?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, ejs

I have the following code.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <% for(let i=0;i<seats.length;i++) { %>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h3> <%= seats[i].name %> </h3>
                    <% if(<%= seats[i].isBook %> == false) { %>
                        <% document.querySelector("h3").disabled = true; %>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
>           at d:\seat booking\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:710:19
>           at Array.forEach()
>           ...

Comment: Try changing your if sentence for: `<% if (seats[i].isBook == false) { %>`. Also, you should paste your code in the question instead of linking an image.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is your `if` sentence. You are opening the tag `<%` and before closing it you are opening another one, which doesn't work and is not needed.

You can try the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% for(let i=0;i<seats.length;i++) { %>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3> <%= seats[i].name %> </h3>
                <% if(seats[i].isBook == false) {
                    document.querySelector("h3").disabled = true;
                } %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I did not just remove the tags within the `if(..)`. The other tags I removed are also unnecessary, because you don't have any `HTML` code in between your `if` sentence.